# MySql counting rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I'm trying to get the number of replies and no replies from a message with one mysql query.
For example, I send "Hey what's up?" to 20 people, I want to know how many replies I got and how many no replies.
I have a table Thread and lookup table Message.

Thread table has columns:

```
1.threadId (varchar)
2.messageGuid (varchar)
3.messageLookupId (int)
4.fromId (varchar)
5.toId (varchar)
6.replied (tinyint(1))
7.dateSent (timestamp)
```

Message table has columns:

```
1.id (int)
2.message (text)
```

Thread and Message tables can be joined by `Thread.messageLookupId = Message.id`

I would like to have a results table with columns:

```
message | totalSent | replied | notReplied | repliedPercentage | notRepliedPercentage
```

I've tried

### Query

```
SELECT Message.message, count(Message.id) replied 
FROM Thread
JOIN Message
ON Thread.messageLookupId = Message.id
WHERE replied LIKE 1
Group by Message.id
ORDER BY replied DESC
```

replied=0 means not replied
replied=1 means replied

This only returns the number that replied but i'm stuck with getting the other columns that I want:

```
totalSent | notReplied | repliedPercentage | notRepliedPercentage
```

repliedPercentage and notRepliedPercentage would return the percentages of replied and notReplied

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data or a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do sum using replied column value.

```
SELECT Message.id, sum( replied) as replied, 
      sum(replied=0) as notReplied, 
      sum(replied)/count(message.id)*100 repliedPercentage, 
      sum(replied=0)/count(message.id)*100 as notRepliedPercentage
FROM Thread
JOIN Message
ON Thread.messageLookupId = Message.id
Group by Message.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT Message.id,
       Count(1)                    totalSent,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN replied = 1 THEN 1
             END)                  AS replied,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN replied = 0 THEN 1
             END)                  AS notReplied,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN replied = 1 THEN 1
             END) / Count(1) * 100 repliedPercentage,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN replied = 0 THEN 1
             END) / Count(1) * 100 AS notRepliedPercentage
FROM   Thread
       JOIN Message
         ON Thread.messageLookupId = Message.id
GROUP  BY Message.id
```